# Free JPEG2000 Library or SDK for de-compression

Tags: windows, sdk, jpeg2000

I have written code to compress and decompress image files using a proprietary SDK for transmission from an aircraft via satellite. Unfortunately a license must be purchased for decompression as well as compression.  Until now my applications have been mostly used in-house so I can keep track of the licenses and distribution.  Now I need to provide the applications for outsiders and I can neither control distribution nor want to pay for the licenses.

Does anyone know of free de-compression programs, SDKs, or libraries?  I program in C++ for Windows NT, 2000, XP.

My image files are raw data, monochrome, with 16bit unsigned pixels and the compression that is used is lossless or very mildly lossy.

Comment: I'm not an SO Lawyer, but I fail to see the defect in this question. I note that it did not in fact solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion, so whatever heuristic was used to predict that failed in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a thought, but the de facto standard for JPEG2000 is [Kakadu](http://www.kakadusoftware.com/) because Dr. Taubman pretty much wrote the JPEG2000 standard.  Although it costs some money, it is the best library that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could be a good starting point: [OpenJPEG](http://www.openjpeg.org/). If it doesn't meet your requirements then ask at their forum for some hints.

Some people at my university used [jj2000](http://jj2000.epfl.ch/) for various tests. However it is in Java...

Comment: I've had success with OpenJPEG in Windows. (C#; I wrote my own wrapper in C and call that DLL with C#). It's kind of slow but it works.

Comment: @JaredUpdike that sounds great! Is you wrapper open source or awailable for download?

Answer (score 2):

also libjasper:  [link text](http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~mdadams/jasper/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [j2k-codec](http://j2k-codec.com/)  It's not free but not expensive either.

I've bought it (v1.7) myself and been using it for 4 years. Decoding is very fast, no error encountered so far.

For encoding, I use ER Mapper SDK.

I don't know how much improvements `Jasper` or `OpenJPEG` has shown these years, but those free libraries were too slow for my use. (Both encoding and decoding slow)

Answer (score 1):

Magick++ is a C++ binding for ImageMagick that I *think* exposes ImageMagick's JPEG-2000 functionality. ImageMagick uses libjasper, which Doug mentioned. This might do the trick for you (and hopefully for me, too).

Comment: ImageMagick now uses OpenJPEG instead of JasPer for dealing with JPEG 2000 http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25357

Answer (score -9):

Why would anyone tagetting the windows platform pay someone for a Jpeg library when GdiPlus does it already?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533844(VS.85).aspx

should be a good starting point. gdiplus has the 2nd best jpeg decompression speedwise (in my tests for whatever that counts for). And is distributed as an OS component with Windows 5 and up. i.e. Windows XP and greater.

If, for any reason, GdiPlus is unacceptable...

Intel used to distribute a jpeg decompression * compression library, inventively named the "intel jepg library" or ijl. the redistributable consists of a single dll, ijl15.dll 
If you can find the original distribution, its licensed for free distribution and use. Intel just dont host it any more. Its been replaced with the intel performance primitives library, which does contain jpeg compression and decompression, but the per seat licensing is very fair, and again theres no limit on redistribution of the *coff* redistributables.

Comment: There's a difference between JPEG and JPEG2000.  JPEG2000 is a totally different animal with much better compression.