# JPEG-LS / LOCO-I compression library

Tags: delphi, image, compression, jpeg

What implementations are available for the JPEG-LS compression standard? JPEG-LS is the new (relatively speaking) lossless JPEG format based on the HP LOCO-I (LOw COmplexity LOssless COmpression for Images) algorithm.

I am aware of the HP reference implementation which appears to no longer come with source code, and the following third-party implementations:

[UBC](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~jakulin/jpeg-ls/), [CharLS](http://www.codeplex.com/CharLS) , [Clunie](http://www.dclunie.com/jpegls.html)

The CharLS library seems to be the most current and only one that is actively maintained. Are there any other implementations available that I have missed?

I am mainly interested in 16-bit grayscale compression and need a version that works (or can be adapted to work) on Win32. An implementation or wrapper compatible with Delphi would be ideal. CharLS seems to be quite good, but is C/C++ rather than pure C library and cannot be directly linked into a Delphi application due to its use of C++ features.

Comment: Haven't seen it so this is just thinking out loud: can it be compiled under C++ Builder?

Comment: I did a quick test a few days ago and it compiles with a bunch of warnings, mostly about mixing signed/unsigned values. Not sure this buys much though.

Answer (score -1):

As i remember teh JPEG-LS is part of the JPEG 2000 specs, so somethig count propobly be found searching for that.
Se also [Free JPEG2000 Library or SDK for de-compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622020/free-jpeg2000-library-or-sdk-for-de-compression)

[Leadtools.com](http://Leadtools.com) have a comercial library

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. JPEG-LS is actually a separate standard from JPEG 2000. JPEG-LS uses the LOCO-I algorithm (developed by HP) in place of wavelets and has better compression/speed characteristics (see http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg/jpegls.html). LeadTools was a good suggestion, but they do not seem to support JPEG-LS for some reason.